# What survey text in math or proofs need I reference to justify a colon to separate a symbol that substitutes for a statement?

Tags: reference-request, notation, recreational-mathematics, education

If this is a noob question, apologies, I am a noob.

So, I understand the understand the colon in the sense of (Book of Proof; Hammack; 2018):

$$X=\{epression:rule\}$$

And certainly I see the use of colon in something like the following to give a name that stands for an expression/rule:

\begin{matrix}
[\alpha..\beta] & \text{closed interval}: \text{the set }\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid  \alpha \leqslant x \leqslant \beta \}
\end{matrix}

Remembering we are talking usage of ":", so starting with this formula (sans ":"):

$$\forall *.\phi_{1}\land ... \land \phi_{n} \to \varphi$$

I found this formula in a paper that references out to Antony Galton (Logic for Information Technology, John Wiley & Sons, Chichester, England, October 1990).   That formula, from Galton according to the referenced paper, is an "implication formula" denoted by $\psi$.   Since the point of having a symbol to stand for the expression was to use the symbol in other expressions, I opted to summarise that in my paper as:

$$\psi:\forall *.\phi_{1}\land ... \land \phi_{n} \to \varphi$$

My justification was that "Book Of Proof"(Hammack, 2018) opts into explaining use of letters such as P, Q, R and S to stand for specific statements.   Galton clearly was using $\psi$ rather than P, Q,  R or S to stand for "implication formula".   The colon was used in Hammack to separate the symbol from the statements.  I take Hammack to be implying approach is common knowledge.

Is there a survey text on math or proof, other than Hammack, that introduces the form:

$$symbol:statements$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there a reason why it is inappropriate to spend a sentence or two explaining the notation? (Incidentally, I've seen that notation, but it's not the only symbol used in that position.)

Comment: Not inappropriate if this were a math paper, the question is however about the use of colon.  Any statements could stand in place of the ones I have used.  The focus is on if it is legal, and if it is general knowledge it need not be explained in the paper. So the question is what survey text on math or proofs (or both) introduces that use of colon into the wild?  If you have seen the symbol used then where please and was it in a survey text that would place use of colons in the general knowledge category, since my PhD coordinator seems to feel it is not in the general knowledge catetory.